# Angular - how to http service subscribe without response

Tags: angular

I am trying to make a login component in angular 7. I have created all the necessary services for signup and login and they are working. But I also want to handle the situation when userid/email is not found in the database and show a message on the client side.

*login.component.html*

```
<div *ngIf="invalidLogin">Invalid username or email</div>
```

*login.component.ts*

```
constructor(private usersrv: UsersService) {}

onLogin() {
  const user: UserDetails = { 
    userid: "user",       
    email: "user@test.com",
    password: "123"     
  }  
  return this.usersrv.login(user)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log('response found');
        this.invalidLogin = false;
      },
      err => {
        console.log('response not found');
        this.invalidLogin = true;
      }
    );
}
```

*user.service.ts*

```
login(user) {
  return this.http.post(`${this.url}/login`, user)  
}
```

It works well when I enter valid user `"email: "user@test.com"` and prints `response found` on console but does not print `response not found` when I enter invalid user which is not present in the database, like `"email: "notauser@test.com"`.

It looks like it does not come in else part when there is no response for service and change this.invalidLogin accordingly. Please suggest how to handle this case.

Thanks

Comment: Hi i just want to  know  when  login is invalid then are you  getting  the  200 status code any  other status code  such as 400 etc.

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions

In the first one you can throw an exception from the server side, if the user is invalid. In that case the following code works

```
    return this.usersrv.login(user)
           .subscribe(res => {
               console.log('response found');
               this.invalidLogin = false;
               },
               err => {
               console.log('response not found')
               this.invalidLogin = true;
               });
  }
```

In the second case the exception is thrown at the server side but the status code is set to 401 (unauthorized).In that case there is some changes in the code.Your service should look like this.

```
login(user){
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/login`, user,{observe: 'response'})  
  }
```

login.component.ts

```
  constructor(private usersrv: UsersService) {}

  onLogin() {
      const user:UserDetails = { 
        userid: "user",       
        email: "user@test.com",
        password: "123"     
      }  
      return this.usersrv.login(user)
             .subscribe(res => {
                 if(res.status==200){
                 console.log('response found');
                 this.invalidLogin = false;
                 } 
                 else{
                   console.log('response not found')
                   this.invalidLogin = true;
                 }
                 //status code should be 401 for unauthorized user
                 });
    }
```

Status code should be 401 for unauthorized user. The above else clause is a generic one

Comment: Thanks @Faizal. You gave a big lead to the solution. using your answer I solved the problem. I also had to sent the response from the route (used in service) , in else part of findone command. User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, (err, result) => { if (result){...} else {return res.status(200).json({message: 'usernotfound'}); And in component.ts, checked for the "message" in response.

Answer (score 0):

hi error is not else part of subscribe function, its trigger when exception occurred on server side or sent error by server or internet connectivity issue
if you want handle this problem you have send data from server. e.g if email found then send  true value server then check in subscribe 
you have send value from server isEmailFound check in subs function

```
return this.usersrv.login(user)
       .subscribe(res => {
           console.log('response found');
           this.invalidLogin = res.isEmailFound;
           },
           err => {
           console.log('something went wrong')
           this.invalidLogin = false;
           });
```

}